# A variation of fibonacci assembly x86, have to call it from a c++ main method, kind of lost at few parts

Tags: c++, assembly, fibonacci

This is the fibonacci code,

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned int n)
{
if (n==1 || n ==2)
return 1;
else
return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
}
```

but instead for my code, I have to change formula to a new one,
f(n-2)/2 + f(n-1) * 2, so the sequence is 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 44, 98, 218

I need to write a recursive function called Mobonacci in assembly to calculate the nth number in sequence, and also a main function in c++ that reads a positive number n, then cals mobonacci assembly function with parameter n, then print our result

So I'm kind of confused, do I write the function in assembly like I did below, then write a c++ function to call it? and how would guys change my code from fibonacci to the new formula? Here is my code, what do I need to change and did I need create new part that let the code read input? Also is my code too short? do I need add anything else?

```
.code
    main PROC
        mov ecx,0
        push 4          ; calculate the nth fib
        call Fib            ; calculate fib (eax)
        call WriteDec
        call Crlf
        exit
    main ENDP

    Fib PROC
        add ecx,1
        push ebp
        mov  ebp,esp
        mov  eax,[ebp+8]    ; get n
        cmp  eax,2      ; n == 2?
        je   exception2     
        cmp  eax,1      ; n == 1?
        je   exception2         
        dec eax
        push eax            ; Fib(n-1)
        call fib

        add eax,
        jmp Quit


    Exception2:
        dec eax
    Quit:
        pop  ebp            ; return EAX
        ret  4          ; clean up stack
    Fib ENDP

    END main
```

Comment: If you have a working Fibonacci function and just need to change it to do Mobonacci, which also uses the prior two terms in the recursive definition, you should try that modification yourself and ask if you get stuck on something. If it's your Fibonacci code, changing it should be simple. As far as the boundary between C++ and asm, then you are correct: write the asm function, called from C++, which calculates the n-th number, given `n`, and return it to C++. In C++, you are just retrieving `n` from the user, calling the asm function, and displaying the result to the user.

Comment: You'll need to make your `Fib` function callable from C++, so you'll need to look up the x86 call stack convention for that. At a glance, it looks like it's following it, but just be sure. You won't need the asm `main` function.

Comment: Tell your compiler to print an assembly language listing of the `fib` function.  Compare it to what you have.

Comment: @Lurker thank you so much, also can I send you my fib code in assembly, you can feel free to correct it!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you are trying to insert asm code into your c++ code...
For gcc/linux you can do something like :

```
    //Simple example:
    void *frame; /* Frame pointer */
    __asm__ ("mov %%ebp,%0":"=r"(frame));

   //Complicated example:
   int foo(void) {
     int joe=1234, fred;
     __asm__( 
        "  mov %1,%%eax\n"
        "  add $2,%%eax\n"
        "  mov %%eax,%0\n"
        :"=r" (fred) /* %0: Out */
        :"r" (joe) /* %1: In */
        :"%eax" /* Overwrite */
     );
     return fred;
  }
```

The important thing is to understand how to use your asm function in cpp.
You can find some useful things about this subject here : https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2011/fall/cs301/lecture/10_12_asm_c.html

About the second part of your question.
To multiple, you can use the command "**mul**" and to make a division "**div**".
So if you want to do f(n-1) * 2 
You have to get you register **%eax** after the "**call fib**" and use mul.

Just have a look here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm

Comment: Thank so much! is there anything else you would change about my code? did I do the code in a recursive way? and also don't I need a loop in my code? my professor said something about that in an example.

Comment: also is there anyway that you can commment or correct my assembly code?